# GTest: mocking non-virtual member function

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest

Consider the following snippet of code:

> source.hpp

```
class tracker
{
public:
  static tracker& get_instance()
  {
    static tracker instance;
    return instance;
  }

  tracker(const tracker&) = delete;
  tracker& operator=(const tracker&) = delete;

private:
  tracker()
  {
     _ip_count = settings::get_instance().get_ips();
     // ...
  }

private:
  int _ip_count;
};
```

> test.cpp

```
#include "source.hpp"
#include "settings.hpp"

#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

struct MockSettings
{
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(get_ips, int());
};

TEST(tracker, _)
{
  // Need to mock settings::get_instance().get_ips() function here
  tracker& inst = tracker::get_instance();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

As you can see in the `test.cpp` I'm getting instance of `tracker`, hence `settings::get_instance().get_ips()` function is called. Actually, I don't need to call the latter function, instead, I would like to return, e.g., `3`. How can I do it considering that `get_ips()` is *non-virtual* function. I don't want to change the source codes if it is possible. Also I read the following documentation https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md, but couldn't achieve the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem you might be having here is that you're trying to mock the class `settings`, but there's no way for the constructor of tracker to actually *use* your mock settings class, because it's fixed at compile-time to directly refer to `settings`.

The cookbook does actually explain how to solve this, under "[Mocking Nonvirtual Methods](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#MockingNonVirtualMethods)": First, you make your mock class, then you provide some means of *dependency injection* that allows you to select between the production and mock versions of the class at compile time. One way to do this would be to make tracker a class template parametrised with the settings class with something like:

```
template <typename settings_class> class tracker_template
{
public:
  static tracker_template<settings_class>& get_instance()
  {
    static tracker_template<settings_class> instance;
    return instance;
  }

// ...

private:
  tracker_template()
  {
     _ip_count = settings_class::get_instance().get_ips();
     // ...
  }

// ...
};
```

After which you could eg. `using tracker = tracker_template<settings>;` to continue using tracker in your production code, and instead use `tracker_template<MockSettings>` in your test code.

There probably isn't a way to solve this without changing your code.